# Что есть хорошая практика в Symfony (разделение логики)?

Tags: symfony2, symfony3, dependency-injection, best-practice

Сейчас провожу тестирование и рефакторинг кода в связи с этим есть несколько вопросов по правильной архитектуре приложения в Symfony.
Задача контроллера ясна, нужно принять параметры, передать в сервис, там обработать логику и вернуть контроллеру результат. Но часто в логике сервисов нужно проработать данные с базы данных. Поэтому есть вопрос, можно ли в сервисах вызывать базу данных? У меня почти в каждом сервисе есть или внедрение зависимости от entity manager или определенных репозиториев, это нормально? Или стоит все это делать в контроллере? Можно ли в сервисе сохранять данные в базу данных? У меня есть сервис для оплаты, там я выполняю все проверки, а затем сохраняю оплату в базу данных. Конечно это все можно делать и через контроллер и даже легче (не нужно внедрять лишние зависимости), но без конструкций if, else тут не обойтись.
Тот же вопрос можно отнести и к event listener и handler. У меня есть проверка, каждый раз, сколько оплаченных дней осталось у пользователя. Для этого я несколько раз обращаюсь в бд в наблюдателе.
Я делаю правильно? Или все-таки стоит жестко ограничивать функции сервиса и контроллера? Буду рад любым подсказкам.

Comment: контроллер не должен иметь прямого доступа к бд, тлько к представителю domain model. сервисам нужен доступ к бд.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы правильно делаете, что сохраняете контроллеры тонкими. Контроллер - это уровень HTTP, его возможные задачи - это разбор параметров запроса (если они ещё не были разобраны на этапе роутинга) и оформление ответа (в смысле формата данных - HTML, JSON, etc).

> Поэтому есть вопрос, можно ли в сервисах вызывать базу данных? У меня почти в каждом сервисе есть или внедрение зависимости от entity manager или определенных репозиториев, это нормально?

В целом, да, это вполне нормально. Но дать однозначный ответ невозможно: это сильно зависит от специфики вашего приложения, от предметной области, от общей архитектуры.

> Или все-таки стоит жестко ограничивать функции сервиса и контроллера?

Функции сервиса должны быть ограничены его задачами (ваш К.О.). Помните о single responsibility, не создавайте God-объектов. Разделяйте сервисы на слои, выносите общие функции в отдельные библиотеки/компоненты.

Хорошие практики разделения логики Symfony - это хорошие практики разработки ПО в целом и подобные рекомендации могут быть только максимально общими.  Например, вы можете руководствоваться паттернами [DDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design). Можно [Фаулера](http://martinfowler.com/articles/enterprisePatterns.html) почитать.
Есть "официальные" [Symfony Best Practices](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/index.html). Также могу посоветовать материал от мейнтейнера Doctrine о [хороших практиках в ORM](https://ocramius.github.io/doctrine-best-practices/#/).

Читайте, выбирайте, что вам больше подходит.

Comment: У Marco "ocramius" Pivetta недавно был ещё доклад об этом https://youtu.be/WW2qPKukoZY
Но там много спорных моментов - для разминки мозга хорошо, а для применения на практике нельзя всё брать и использовать.

Comment: Да, я как раз на слайды из этого доклада и оставил ссылку в ответе. Имхо, там всё перечисленное можно (и часто нужно) использовать, но, конечно, не бездумно )

Answer (score 2):

Если проект не слишком сложный, то удобнее всего сделать единую точку получения entities из DB - репозитории.

Что может делать репозиторий:

- **findBySomething** - получить много entities по условию
- **findOneBySomething** - получить одну entity или null по условию
- **findOneOrCreateBySomething** - получить одну entity по условию, если нет, то создать
- **getBySomething** - получить одну entity по условию или выбросить исключение, если нет
- **countSomething** - получить сразу результат (sum, avg, count, max, ...), когда это лучше, чем получать entities и их обрабатывать
- **updateSomething** - обновление данных в базе данных, если это лучше, чем получать entities, обрабатывать и делать `$em->flush`

Репозиторий не должен содержать сложную логику, которая не связана напрямую с базой данных. Это выносится в сервисы.

У сервиса в зависимостях может быть репозиторий и, если нужно, EntityManager.

Контроллеры общаются с репозиторием и EntityManager, если надо просто получить данные из формы и сохранить. Если нужна более сложная логика, то через сервисы.

Этот подход подходит для большинства типичных проектов.

Comment: В основном согласен с рекомендациями, но по поводу логики в репозиториях готов поспорить. Всё зависит от того, как вы используете ORM: в случае rich domain model логика может быть (и должна быть) даже в сущностях. А репозитории по сути те же сервисы, в них вполне может быть доменная логика (и обычно она там есть - хотя бы на уровне DQL-запросов).

Comment: Когда в репозиториях меньше логики, то: 1) больше логики можно протестировать без базы данных; 2) легче поменять способ получения и сохранения данных (базу данных обычно менять нет смысла, а вот изменить получение данных на кеш или внешний сервис - вполне вероятно)

Comment: Аргументы правильные, но на каждое решение найдётся кейс в котором оно не подойдет. Например, 1) - размещение логики в DQL запросе может увеличить производительность там, где она важней тестируемости метода, а 2) - способ получения и сохранения данных также может никогда не меняться. Контекст всегда разный, особенно когда речь идет о бизнес-логике. В целом-то я с вами согласен, просто хотел обратить внимание на то, что на уровне домена, где обычно и участвует доктрина, может быть всякое.

Comment: Кстати, немного не по теме, но возможно будет интересно: [немного критики репозиториев в Doctrine и альтернативные решения](http://www.whitewashing.de/2013/03/04/doctrine_repositories.html) от beberlei